# how could a new gem in Gemfile (AccessGranted) with no dependencies break ActionView/Jbuilder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, actionview, actioncontroller, jbuilder

In a rails 5.1 project, I have a controller like `Api::V1::ResourcesController` with a method like `#create`; I eventually invoke `render status: 201, formats: :json`. This has, as I expect, been resulting in a load of a Jbuilder view located at `app/views/api/v1/resources/create.json.jbuilder`.

I recently added the `AccessGranted` gem to my project, and after doing so (with no code changes), I find that my invocation of `render` is still producing the desired `201` status, but is always producing  (single space character) as the body. Furthermore, some inspection with `pry` seems to suggest the file is not being found by the `lookup_context`, however I can't say why this is as I don't really know how to trace the causal hierarchy here.

---

Update:

I have found that once I include AccessGranted, the ancestry of my controller class no longer includes `ActionView::Rendering`. It includes `AccessGranted::Rails::ControllerMethods` as intended, but has no other changes to ancestry.

---

The thing that disturbs me here is that AccessGranted is a tiny gem, and I have been able to review it in its entirety in about twenty minutes, without any indication in it as to why it would muck with rails. Is there even something specific I could look for in the new gem to tell what it might be changing just by its inclusion in the gem file?

Ideally I would like to know what exactly has happened here, but even without that I have some difficulty navigating the dynamic ruby system to start getting reliable traces of these files. Some things I have tried in my investigation:

- inspected the Controller object. I see that it has not experienced a change of `formats` or `_prefixes`
- walked through the flow leading to setting the response. The jbuilder is invoked during `render_templates` in the good case, but after adding the gem, it is NEVER invoked
- tried to invoke methods directly on `lookup_context` while prying, but not reached conclusive results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the gem in question (AccessGranted) invokes a `class_eval` on `ActionController::API` at module load time, which is before Jbuilder's rail tie invocation, and thus Jbuilder has not yet executed its patch to `ApiController`. As such, `ActionController::API`, which was a parent to my controller class, was loaded as such without `ActionView::Rendering`.

This load order is not canonical in Rails as far as I can tell, so I consider this a problem with AccessGranted. As such, I submitted a PR to AccessControl to have it conform to the Rail Tie hook mechanism.